# Users are stored where in ASPX and VS?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using a default .aspx web forms example in Visual Studio 2010 and I am curious if anyone can speak to how the default login/register system stores the user's information. From what I can tell this is not stored in any kind of SQL type table.

Is it known exactly where this file is located, and how would one interface with that? I would like that table to contain a URL for each user in addition to their password. ( I am guessing the 'table' only contains user and password ).

Is this possible or would I be better of creating my own login/register system? I know it wouldn't be that much coding, but it would sure be nice to utilize what is already there.

Please spare me if this is easily edited up in a menu somewhere. Was unknowingly thrown into a aspx project with little previous experience. Taking in info as fast as I can!

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Comment: Aren't they stored in the aspnetdb database?

Comment: Yes, it looks like in aspnet_Membership. I guess I am just confused as to the whole database setup in asp.net. So are the aspnetdb's created by default? It seems so. In a similar question the user was told to look into the "asp.net sql server registration tool" and to create a "profile" for each user. Is a profile necessary? Can I not just add one more row to that membership table?

Comment: You need to add the whole thing. The [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) class has all the methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`Membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx) class you have access to all the methods you need. This class includes methods for:

- Creating users
- Changing their password
- Deleting Users
- etc.

The users are stored in the `aspnetdb` and the information is in several tables. The main ones are:

- aspnet_User - this stores the users
- aspnet_Applications - which applications are running
- aspnet_Membership - this relates the users to the applications they are authorised for
- aspnet_Profile - user profile information the the application

This is a standard SQL database that exists on your SQL Server.

For a fuller explanation read [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

The users are stored in the ASPNETDB.MDF database in the App_Data folder.This file is hidden by default so I can understand why you're confused.

To make ASPNETDB visible - select the App_Data folder in Solution Explorer and click *Show All Files*.

[image]

Now if you click on the .mdf file the database will open in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

The user information is located in the aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership tables.

The query below will return the user id, user name,encrypted password and email:

```
SELECT aspnet_Users.UserId, aspnet_Users.UserName, aspnet_Membership.Password, aspnet_Membership.Email
FROM     aspnet_Users INNER JOIN
                  aspnet_Membership ON aspnet_Users.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
```